# Open CSV file in background and retrieve worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel, csv, worksheet

My VBA project consists on cleaning databases.

I'm using a Userform, and this is the code i wrote till now.

I have been successful at importing a file, but i still can't perform actions on it.

1. I need you guys to show me how can i get the workbook name and worksheets of the .csv file i just imported to start assigning actions referring to the database by its workbook name and worksheet name.
2. I'd also appreciate it if you can show me how to keep my userform on top, or how to import the .csv file without displaying it

*code*

```
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant

Private Sub importedworkbook_Click()
MsgBox "imported workbook : " & _
fNameAndPath
End Sub


Private Sub Importbutton_Click()

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files Only (*.CSV), *.XLS", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath
End Sub
```

Comment: Declare a workbook variable, say wb, and set the csv file you open to it: Set wb = Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath then you can use wb to work with it. Same with sheets: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

Comment: A CSV file is a text file, not an excel file.You're complicating things by involving excel here

Answer (score 1):

Best to use declared variables to reference the opened CSV sheet

```
Private wsCSV as Worksheet

Private Sub Importbutton_Click()
    Dim wb as Workbook
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files Only (*.CSV), *.XLS", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fNameAndPath)
    Set wsCSV = wb.Worksheets(1) ' A csv file will only ever have one sheet
End Sub
```

Variable `wsCSV` now refers to the CSV sheet, and can be referenced in other code in the UserForm module

Answer (score 0):

You can open a second instance of Excel to work with the hidden file

```
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files Only (*.CSV), *.XLS", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

    Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)
    Set wsCSV = wb.Worksheets(1)

    MsgBox wsCSV.Name
    ' do stuff

    'close second instance  
    wb.Close False
    objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
```